# columns.Clear doesn't work

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

This is my code for my UserDynamicSetsControl:

```
public ReportData ReportData
        {
            get { return reportData; }
            set
            {                               
                reportData = value;

                this.bsDynasets.DataSource = reportData;             

            }
        }

 public TypeOfBuilding TypeOfBuilding
        {
            get { return _typeOfBuilding; }
            set
            {
                _typeOfBuilding= value;

                dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();



                if (this.TypeOfBuilding== TypeOfBuilding.House)
                {
                    CreateColumnsForHouses();

                }
                else if (this.TypeOfBuilding== TypeOfBuilding.Flat)
                {
                    CreateColumnsForFlats();

                }

                if (this.bsDynasets.DataSource != null)
                    this.bsDynasets.Filter = "TypeOfBuilding= " + (int)_typeOfBuilding;


            }
        }




public voidCreateColumnsForFlats()
{
 this.dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] { this.ColumnsA,ColumnB};
}

public voidCreateColumnsForFlats()
{
 this.dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] { this.ColumnsC,ColumnD};
}
```

At first ReportData is set and then TypeOfBuilding. It appears that after I change TypeOfBuilding all columns will clear and a new one will be added. Instead, it keeps old columns and adds new.

After execution of:

```
 this.dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] { this.ColumnsC,ColumnD};
```

there are two columns.

Before calling

```
  dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
```

it shows the correct number of columns (i.e., 4,6,8,etc.). Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: Not seeing what your issue is...but you're supplying AddRange two columns so seeing 2 columns afterwards is expected. (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumncollection.addrange(v=VS.100).aspx)

Comment: before it exit from CreateColumnsForFlats() or CreateColumnsForInvestment() I see in quickWatch there is 2 column. And this is what I want, but after execution all method I see at GUI four columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set [`.AutoGenerateColumns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns.aspx) to `false` on `dataGridView1`.